# jQuery UI AutoComplete not working in wordpress?

Tags: jquery

To use jQuery UI AutoComplete, I loaded the following scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget'); 
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-position');

wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete',   $ul .'/css/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css' );
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete', $url .'/js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.8.2', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete', $url .'/js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js', '1.1', true );
```

After the above scripts, I loaded my own js which includes the following code:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#to").autocomplete({
        // code...
   });
});
```

Firebug shows all scripts and style are loaded and gives error message of "$ is not a function". How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress requires no conflict wrappers for jQuery.

```
(function($){   
    $("#to").autocomplete({
        // code...
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Or:

```
jQuery(function(){   
    jQuery("#to").autocomplete({
        // code...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use for wp_enqueue_scrip following one liner:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete', '', array('jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position'), '1.8.6');
```

As jquery-ui-autocomplete is part of the WP Framework -> [see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

In my coding I use the autocompletion feature the same way @Chris_O mentioned:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var availableTags = ["Batman", "Spiderman", "Hulk"];
            $( "#foo" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
    });
```

To load so many scripts, like in your example is not neccessary, cause jquery is loaded by default from the wp framework. I would recommend to clean up your script initializing and reduce it to the min, load only the scripts you needed. Please take a look at the [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Where does that `availableTags` come from?

Comment: this is my list with my autocomplete values. See edit on my post. If you type 'Ba' it will suggest 'Batman'.

Comment: Could you go into more detail please how about how to properly enqueue and use scripts that are already part of the wordpress framework? I too want to use autocomplete, and I saw in the docs where it's included. I do not see them in my header, and my autocomplete script doesn't work. (although, it does work fine if I use a page template header that links only to the jquery autocomplete files from the autocomplete demo). Do I need to do something special before I can use a script like you have in your answer?